# Right way to include google font in GWT application

Tags: css, gwt, fonts

I have installed google font roboto on my machine,  I am also including

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,medium,bold,thin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

in  tag of my welcome.html file .

and in css file I am using css like

```
.mycss{
font-family: "robotoregular","sans-serif","arial";
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Its working fine in development mode, but when I deploy it on tomcat font size is 2-3px large than development mode. I don't know why its coming. can somebody help me to get out of this? Also how to import Google font in gwt.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it should be:

```
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
```

You can include Google font in your GWT html file the same way as you did for your welcome.html. This is the link that Google recommends (you can choose your own font weights, of course):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei I have included the same link. But now in developement mode my font size is 2-3 px bigger than its actual size when I load the page.

Comment: The problem you describe is not related to the font import. In your browser dev tools you can see which rules have been applied to font-size property. Compare dev mode and production - this may tell you what causes this problem.